# Is this a P-wave on single-lead ECG

Tags: electrocardiogram, sinus

I am an engineer working on a project using ECGs. I am trying a few techniques and I was wondering whether the P-wave is still visible in the ECG after filtering it. The issue is that I believe the annotation I added on the image seems to be too close to the QRS to be a P-wave and the amplitude seems small.

Can someone confirm please (it is supposed to be sinus rhythm)? 
Also, do you have any advise on identifying P-waves manually?

Thank you in advance.[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: That image isn't a normal ECG and there are no axis labels or timing marks, so the answer is kind of a shot in the dark. Judging by the width of the other waves, I'd say what you've circled is far too wide to be a P wave. That P wave would be as wide as the entire QRS.

Comment: Hello, I will add a few more images to help. The ticks are not visible, I dont know why. The graph is divided to 0.2s (large rectangular areas) each sub-divided to 0.04s

Comment: Thank you, much better images. I think the P waves are pretty obvious in these recordings and I'm not a doctor, so have you attempted to discover how to identify a P wave? This site requires questions to demonstrate some degree of prior research.

Comment: I have indicated the QRS complex with green dots and where I believe the P-wave starts and ends. From info I found the PR segment is 0.12s-0.2s long but the Pwave seems longer than the QRS wave.

Comment: Also, I have places the red horizontal line at 0 mV

Comment: In the bottom image, you have 3 „waves“ between any two R spikes. Is this an ECG of a healthy patient? In that case, it looks a bit off. If it is the ECG of someone with atrial fibrillation or AV blockage, maybe get an ECG recording of a healthy individual?

Comment: What species is the ECG from?

Comment: It is from a public 12-lead ECG that can be found here :https://physionet.org/content/ptb-xl/1.0.1/ I am using lead 1